# Can't create pipenv 3.10 environment | AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'

Tags: python, pipenv

I am looking to create a pipenv environment with 3.10, however, it keeps throwing me this error.

`AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'`

Full Output:

```
pipenv install --python /usr/bin/python3.10

Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /usr/bin/python3.10 (3.10.4) to create virtualenv…
⠋created virtual environment CPython3.10.4.final.0-64 in 184ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/spenupala/.local/share/virtualenvs/30-Days-of-Python-Challenge-n3HbSvr8, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, pkg_resources=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/spenupala/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1.debian.1)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

Virtualenv location: /home/spenupala/.local/share/virtualenvs/30-Days-of-Python-Challenge-n3HbSvr8
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
  from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/cookies.py", line 172, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

I've read other solutions of why this error occurs, but not sure why it is stopping me from creating a virtual environment using Pipenv.

Comment: this looks like a python version specific issue. note that importing from `collections` was deprecated and I believe was ultimately removed in 3.10.

Comment: the new syntax is to import from `collections.abc` instead

Answer (score 0):

Installing it using `python3 -m pip install pipenv` instead of `apt-get install` should help. See https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5133